# Any way to have kibana 4 send alerts or take action on specific conditions

Tags: elasticsearch, alert, kibana, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I know Kibana 4 itself does not have alerting and taking action on specific conditions, but I would really want to use Kibana, but also have a way of taking automatic actions or sending alerts if something is not behaving correctly. Are there any solutions or tools that work well together. Currently I am using cloudwatch, elastic search services in AWS. Would all the alerts and actions have to be setup separately in cloudwatch. Maybe I could have kibana generate something on which I could take action, like read from a queue to which kibana sends json alerts or something of that nature?

Comment: For this purpose Elastic has a product called watcher which send alerts or take actions based on conditions.

Comment: You can't use watcher with managed AWS elastic search service since it has a license

Answer (score 4):

[ElastAlert](https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert) looks like an interesting tool. You can define conditions and get alerts as emails or to Slack etc.

> If you have data being written into Elasticsearch in near real time
>   and want to be alerted when that data matches certain patterns,
>   ElastAlert is the tool for you. If you can see it in Kibana,
>   ElastAlert can alert on it.